# Complex WHERE clause in MySQL query - [Use VLOOKUP in MySQL]

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database with following tables ([with sample data](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4607238/testing.sql) in parenthesis):

```
companies {
    id: (1, 2, 3)
    company_name: ('Goog', 'Micr', 'Apple')
}

companies_ratios {
    company_id: (1, 1, 2, 1, 1)
    ratio_id: (1, 2, 1, 4, 5)
    value: (13, 9, 15, 5, 6)
}

ratios {
    id: (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
    ratio_name: ('CAGR', 'Prf. Gwt', 'Sal. Gwt', 'Sales_2012', 'Sales_2011')
    ratio_formula: ('...')
    -- ratio_formula is not used at the moment
}
```

I need to parse user query into MySQL to return matching companies. However, I can't find a solution to parse some simple queries.

Eg. User Queries:

```
Sales_2012 > 1.1 * Sales_2012 AND
CAGR > 13

Prf. Gwt > Sal. Gwt OR
CAGR > Prf. Gwt
```

**Main Problem in parsing above:**
I plan to replace all ratio names in user query with their value in companies_ratios. However, **I need to cross-reference row data. I need something like `value where ratio_id = x` for each ratio_name**. It might be similar to vlookup in excel (to use row data as column).

Comment: I tried various things on paper, like `ratio_id = 1 AND value > 13` but couldn't move further where there were multiple statements or statements where there was a ratio_name on both sides of equation.

Comment: Also, I am posting this after [programmers recommended few great database design alternatives](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/140450/what-is-the-best-approach-for-database-design-with-lots-of-columns) instead of using one giant table and using all ratios as columns. However, while implementing that, I was facing above problem, i.e. how to reference a variable which is dependent on a row data itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been able to create a stored procedure based on the structure you have provided that returns the company id from a string. It is a little complex, and may need others to review it, but it appears to provide the correct results.

```
DELIMITER $$    
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS sp_build_query $$        

CREATE PROCEDURE sp_build_query(IN userquery VARCHAR(100))    
BEGIN    

  DECLARE no_more_rows BOOLEAN;    
  DECLARE rname VARCHAR(50);    
  DECLARE fullsql VARCHAR(1000);    
  DECLARE ratio_cur CURSOR FOR SELECT ratio_name FROM ratios;    

  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND    
    SET no_more_rows = TRUE;    

  SET fullsql = userquery;    

   OPEN ratio_cur;    
   FETCH ratio_cur INTO rname;    
   rnamewhile: WHILE rname is not null DO    
     IF INSTR(fullsql, rname) > 0 THEN    
         SET fullsql = REPLACE(fullsql, rname, CONCAT(' (SELECT `value` FROM companies_ratios INNER JOIN ratios ON companies_ratios.ratio_id = ratios.id WHERE ratios.ratio_name = ''', rname , ''' AND companies_ratios.company_id = cr.company_id ) '));    
     END IF;    
     FETCH ratio_cur INTO rname;         
     IF no_more_rows THEN    
        CLOSE ratio_cur;    
        LEAVE rnamewhile;    
    END IF;    
   END WHILE rnamewhile;    


   SET @finalsql = CONCAT('SELECT company_id FROM companies_ratios cr WHERE ', fullsql , ' GROUP BY cr.company_id;');     

   PREPARE stmt1 FROM @finalsql;     
   EXECUTE stmt1;     
   DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;     
END$$
```

I used the following websites to assist creating the query. They should be able to explain the functions a bit more, but basically it loops through the ratios table, and when it finds a ratio name in the user query it replaces it with a select statement. The resulting statement is the joined together at the end to create your final select statement which is then executed, providing a list of unique company id's.

Execute an STRING as a query - Dynamic SQL -> PREPARE
http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?60,27979,30437

MySQL Forums :: Stored Procedures :: MySQL Stored procedure Tutorial
http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?98,358569,358569

MySQL Cursors
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cursors.html

Loop in Stored Procedures
http://www.mysqltutorial.org/stored-procedures-loop.aspx

SQL Cursor in Stored Procedures
http://www.mysqltutorial.org/sql-cursor-in-stored-procedures.aspx

SQL Syntax for Prepared Statements
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html

CREATE PROCEDURE and CREATE FUNCTION Syntax
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html

Comment: Thanks @Matthew, that was an awesome solution. However, I guess I will need to research more on database design, since in above, with that many SELECT queries, it will cause performance problems. I guess, to use a anything in WHERE clause, it is better to have a column for it. EAV approach (as in above) is good for SELECT queries where queries are not much dynamic. Thanks again Matthew.